# Assertion failed (m.dims >= 2) in Mat

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

Here is the code for image thresholding  I am getting  the error at line 22,

which is:-

**ret,thresh2 = cv2.threshold(img,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)**

Here in this code I want to capture image frames from the video camera and then perform various kinds of thresholding operations on the captured image frames.

I have stored image frames at various instances of time. My objective is to segment the moving objects in the video. Hence I am applying thresholding operation.

Does anybody have any idea, how to do it?

Thanks in advance.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import time
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import sys
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(cam.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cam.read()     #Keep on capturing the frames continuously
    while (ret==True):
        #img = cv2.imread('/home/shrikrishna/Detection&Tracking/OpenCV-Tutorial',6)
        cv2.imwrite('At time'+ str(time.clock()) + '.jpg', frame)
        img2 = cv2.imread('At time'+ str(time.clock()) + '.jpg',6)
        t = str(time.clock())
        cv2.imshow('Orignal',frame)
        k = cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xffff
        if(k==27):              
            #img = cv2.imread('At time'+ str(time.clock()) + '.jpg',6)
            break
        if(k==ord('q')):
            sys.exit(0)
    break

#cv2.imwrite('At time'+ t + '.jpg', frame)
img = cv2.imread('At time'+ t + '.jpg',6)   

ret,thresh1 = cv2.threshold(img,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
ret,thresh2 = cv2.threshold(img,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
ret,thresh3 = cv2.threshold(img,127,255,cv2.THRESH_TRUNC)
ret,thresh4 = cv2.threshold(img,127,255,cv2.THRESH_TOZERO)
ret,thresh5 = cv2.threshold(img,127,255,cv2.THRESH_TOZERO_INV)
titles = ['Original Image','BINARY','BINARY_INV','TRUNC','TOZERO','TOZERO_INV']
images = [img, thresh1, thresh2, thresh3, thresh4, thresh5]

for i in xrange(6):
    plt.subplot(2,3,i+1),plt.imshow(images[i],'gray')
    plt.title(titles[i])
    plt.xticks([]),plt.yticks([])
plt.show()

cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 1):

In the following line, you read in an image as colour image (based on the second parameter -- flags).

```
img = cv2.imread('At time'+ t + '.jpg',6)
```

This means that `img` contains 3 channels, which in Python is represented by a 3-dimensional array.

You immediately use this image as the source for thresholding:

```
ret,thresh1 = cv2.threshold(img,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
```

According to the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#threshold), the first parameter to `threshold()` is:

- src – input array (single-channel, 8-bit or 32-bit floating point).

That means you need a single channel image, e.g. a grayscale image:

```
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret,thresh1 = cv2.threshold(img_gray,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
# ...
```

Another option would be to just read the image as grayscale in first place:

```
img_gray = cv2.imread('At time'+ t + '.jpg',0)
# ...
```